# docker restore from checkpoint - cgroup and mountpoints error

Tags: docker, restore, checkpoint

I am using [docker-checkpoint-restore](https://github.com/boucher/docker/tree/docker-checkpoint-restore) to checkpoint and keep the source container alive (--leave-running) and then restore that checkpoint into a newly created container (with a different IP address).

However, I am having trouble dealing with mountpoints and cgroups. When I start the new container using the checkpoint, I get

```
1: mnt:      Bind /home/abc to ./HOME
1: Error (mount.c:2406): mnt: Can't mount at ./HOME: No such file or directory
1: Error (mount.c:2555): mnt: Unable to statfs ./HOME: No such file or directory
Error (cr-restore.c:1352): 30140 killed by signal 9
Error (cr-restore.c:2182): Restoring FAILED
```

The cgroups error is:

```
 45: Error (cgroup.c:1152): cg: No set 1 found
  1: Error (cr-restore.c:1350): 45 exited, status=1
Error (cr-restore.c:1352): 30140 killed by signal 9
Error (cr-restore.c:2182): Restoring FAILED
```

I presumed this was due to the *mountpoint-12.img* and *cgroup.img* (revealed by using crit decode) having references to the old container id.

```
crit decode -i mountpoints-12.img --pretty | grep nsroot
crit decode -i cgroup.img --pretty | grep docker
```

revealed the old container id.

I followed the same *crit decode -- sed replacement -- crit encode* strategy  that I have used for skinet; but it did not solve the problems. I verified that the *transformed* mountpoints-12.img and cgroup.img have references to the new container id. But the restore still fails with exactly the same error. It is as if the mountpoints transform and the cgroup transforms have not had any impact.

What specifically am I doing wrong ? I have to say that this is the first time I am doing CRIU via docker on a Ubuntu 16.04 xenial image. In the past I have done it for alpine based images and have not had any problems checkpointing into new containers (while the old one is running)

The host system is an Ubuntu Xenial and the default criu/crit is 2.0-2ubuntu3. I upgraded to the latest criu/crit from [xemul criu](https://github.com/xemul/criu) which bumped it to 2.4. However, I get the same errors.

I also tested this against an alpine based container. And it works well. So, perhaps there is something in the Ubuntu xenial based container that is throwing criu (checkpoint, or restore or both) into a tizzy

Any inputs will be welcome.